# Entity Framework MVC Kendo DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass data from my view model through the controller into my dropdownlist, not by using `ViewBag` or `ViewData`, radio buttons and masked textboxes. I am using Entity Framework.

The problem is that I cannot seem to get the controller to pass the view model properties into the view correctly. I have seen many videos and read a bunch of info about doing it with `ViewBag` and `ViewData`. I am thinking I need three separate methods. A `Read` to read and populate the dropdownlist and masked textboxes, an `Edit` to edit them and a `AddNew` to add a new record to the database.

I am not sure how to make this work. It is fine if it is just a regular textbox and not a kendoMasked or kendodropDown

I have a model like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Cars.Models.CarsAppViewModels
{
    public class CarsViewModel
    {       
        [Key]
        public int? IDNumber { get; set; }
        public string CarType { get; set;  }
        public string Ford { get; set; }
        public String Chevy { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> Mazdas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My controller is the part that is giving me fits.

```
namespace Cars.Controllers
{
    public class CarTypeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly CarContext _context;

        public CarTypeController(CarContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Action"] = "Index";            
            return View();
        }

        public List<CarsViewModel> GetCars()
        {
            List<CarsViewModel> list = new List<CarsViewModel>();

            list = _context.Ford.Select(c => new CarsViewModel
            {
               IDNumber = c.IDNumber.ToString(),
               Ford=c.Ford,
               Mazda=c.Mazda
            }).ToList();

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

My view:

```
@model Model.Cars.Models.CarsAppViewModels

 <div class="col-md-11">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
       <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                Car Types
       </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
        <div style="float:inherit; width: 100%;">
           <span>
                <label style="margin:2em;color:#0487c4;">
               make  / Model
               </label>
        @Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
           .Name("CarType").OptionLabel("Choose the Type Of Car From theList")
           .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 50%" })
          </span>
        <ul>
       <li style="color:#0487c4">
       @(Html.Kendo().RadioButton().Name("Company1")
       .Checked(true)
       .HtmlAttributes(new { @name = "company" })
       .Label("Company"))
        </li>
        <li style="color:#0487c4">
        @(Html.Kendo().RadioButton()
       .Name("Person")
       .Checked(true)
       .HtmlAttributes(new { @name = "company" })
       .Label("Individual"))
       </li>
       <li>
      @(Html.Kendo()
      .MaskedTextBox()
      .Name("FirstName")
       </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

I am getting a `NullReference` error.

Comment: What error you get? Please provide all required information and details to make the question good. You did not describe the problem and what you have tried. Are you sure that you get the data from the database correctly and store them in an entity?

Comment: I am getting a Null reference error. Or Object not set to a reference

Comment: Please debug and ensure that `Ford` is not `null`.

Comment: I am sure that the database is fine and I can access information fine , from it just from a kendo grid datasource,and not from the textbox or drop down list

Comment: Ok , I will check on ford not null. I  am wondering does  the code in the controller seem fine otherwise to bring back the dat or do I need the three methods as described  Edit, Read , AddNew?

Comment: Please show what is the exact error, and which line throws the exception.

Comment: To Clarify I , can I do it all from one method or will it require three  to do each separate task.

Comment: I do not understand exactly what you mean, please stick to the code you wrote and describe the exact problem (including the exact exception and which line throws the exception).

Comment: I am not connected to the server so I will not produce run error until I get back on Monday

Comment: Shouldn't the Index () method return View(<model-instance>) ?  Is the model statement in your view correct -- it appears to be specifying a namespace instead of a class?

Comment: In your view, before the <div>, check values received by the view in the model by adding something like:  <script> $( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( @Model.Ford ); // or any other value you want to debug
}); </script>